# How to check disabled push notification in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification

Push notification is very important part in my current developing app. I must know, enabled or disabled push notification globally on phone. How I can make it programmatically in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Push notification is based on a idle TCP connection: when the phone goes online, Google will find and deliver a message if there is any.
So we assume that, if your phone can't go online, there shouldn't be any push notification.
Just try to ban network traffic and internet data globally on the phone, I think that's the only solution.

Comment: and i think u should ban the internet data of Android Market app to prevent this happening.

Comment: Answers on stackoverflow should be with a proper spelling, and avoid abbreviation and txt-speak